# Laravel не открывает заданный URL

Tags: php, laravel, request, route

В контроллере сделана запись вывода поста по ссылке `categories/{catName}/{itemAlias}`
Сам пост открывается согласно той категории где он находится в данный момент.
Но все остальные посты из данной категории открывают только первый пост в категории.
То есть, допустим мы заходим в Категории - Столы - Красный стол с белыми вставками ( он у нас выводится первым в категории, получаем такой url `categories/table/red-table-with-white-elements`, далее переходим в другой пост Категории - Столы Синий стол с серыми вставками, url поменялся `categories/table/blue-table-with-gray-elements`, но на странице выводится информация по красному столу, и так в любой другой пост в любой категории если захожу то открывается только первый пост в этой категории.

Рабочие файлы
**ItemController**

```php
/**
   * @param $catname
   * @return Application|Factory|View|\Illuminate\Foundation\Application
   */
  public function getCategoriesItem($catname)
  {
    $data = Category::where('alias', $catname)->with('services')->firstOrFail();

    if (!$data){
      abort(404, 'Page not found');
    }

    return view('template.sait.page.categories.show', compact('data'))->with('alias', $catname);
  }

  public function getServicesFormCategory($alias)
  {

    $items = Service::whereHas('categories', function ($cat) 
    use($alias)
    {
      $cat->where('alias', $alias);
    })
      ->with('categories')
      ->with('doctors')
      ->firstOrFail();
      
    if (!$items){
      abort(404, 'Page Not found');
    }

    // dd($items);

    return view('template.sait.page.categories.show.view', compact('items'))->with('alias', $alias);
  }
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('categories', [MainController::class, 'getCategories'])->name('sait.categories');
Route::get('categories/{catname}', [MainController::class, 'getCategoriesItem'])->name('sait.categories.show');
Route::get('categories/{catname}/{alias}', [MainController::class, 'getServicesFormCategory'])->name('sait.categories.get.services');
```

**view - show infoCategory**

```php
<h3>{{$data->title}}</h3>

    <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-3 justify-between">
      @foreach($data->services as $link)
        <a 
        class="btn-clc" 
        href="{{
        route('sait.categories.get.services',
        ['alias' => $link->alias, 'catname' => $data->alias])}}">
        {{$link->title}}</a>
      @endforeach
    </div>
```

**view - show infoItem**

```php
<div class="content">
    <span class="text-4xl font-semibold">{{$items->title}}</span> <br>
    <span class="block pt-4 text-lg font-thin">{{$items->description}}</span>

    @foreach ($items->doctors as $doctor )
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>{{ $doctor->id }}</b></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    @endforeach
   </div>
```

Comment: `getServicesFormCategory($alias)` => `getServicesFormCategory($catname, $alias)`

Comment: Если получаете данные через `firstOrFail()` то когда не найдено записей вы получите ошибку [ModelNotFoundException](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ec8fb5596b67de0edfcc8cc7c2167d6c184f080b/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/ModelNotFoundException.php) со статусом 404, поэтому подобное `if (!$items){ abort(404, 'Page Not found'); }` - лишнее, код банально раньше прерываться будет

Comment: @InDevX, Нет как показывало то что находится в категории первым объектом так и показывает эти данные, только меняется URL в адресной строчке

Comment: @InDevX, `dd($alias);` --- `"pokemon" // app\Http\Controllers\MainController.php:49`

Comment: @InDevX, нет - Это то что и должно быть, я тестово создал объект - Название `покемон`, алиас(alias) указывал `pokemon`.

Comment: Но когда я захожу в эту категорию и в этот, адресная строка меняется на значение `(categories/table/pokemon)` в которое вхожу, но вся остальная информация (тип, цвет, материал, описание, изображение) остается от первой записи в этой категории (берется из категории `categories/table/123123`)

Comment: dd($items) -> выводит объект с `ID 22`, хотя если посмотреть то я захожу в объект у которого `ID 25` @InDevX

Comment: Есть подозрение что ошибка в архитектуре имеет место (алиас не у категории должен быть).. замените на `firstOrFail()` на `get()` и покажите что получаете.

Comment: @InDevX, `Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.`. Если начинаю перебирать элементы внутри представления через @foreach(), то получаем список всех объектов которые находятся внутри категории, то есть изначально мы получаем категорию со своим списоком, но когда переходим на любой объект то получаем список всех объектов в этой категории.  
`#items: array:21 [▶]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151024/discussion-between-indevx-and-yura-lons).